# Multiple if statements when separate checking values

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I would like to check if the field has a value (an image in this case), and if it does, then it will display the image. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this. I feel I'm overdoing the if statements. Suggestions?

```
 <img src="<?php the_field('image_1'); ?>" alt="">
<?php if (get_field('image_2')) : ?>
 <img src="<?php the_field('image_2'); ?>" alt="">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (get_field('image_3')) : ?>
 <img src="<?php the_field('image_3'); ?>" alt="">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (get_field('image_4')) : ?>
 <img src="<?php the_field('image_4'); ?>" alt="">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (get_field('image_5')) : ?>
 <img src="<?php the_field('image_5'); ?>" alt="">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (get_field('image_6')) : ?>
 <img src="<?php the_field('image_6'); ?>" alt="">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this code screams for a `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is a better way:

```
<?php foreach (range(2,6) as $digit):
   if (get_field("image_$digit")): 
?>
  <img src="<?php the_field("image_$digit") ?>" alt="" />
<?php 
   endif; endforeach; ?>
```

When you have some set of code lines very similar to each other, think of a way of turning them into a loop. This is just the case, as all the blocks are different only by N in 'image_N' var.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for($a=1;$a<=6;$a++){

    $name = 'image_' . $a;

    if(get_field($name){
        echo "<img src='";
        echo the_field($name);
        echo "' alt='' />";
    }
}
```

i'm not exactly sure what the get_field or the_field functions are so I can't help you there.